# Locating Tactic Notation

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is it possible to Locate where a `Tactic Notation` is defined in Coq?

I know it is possible to locate base tactics using `Locate Ltac basetac`, non-tactic notation with queries such as `Locate "++"`.

For the notation I'm looking for, I can see it in the tactic grammar with `Print Grammar tactic`, but is there a way to locate where it's defined?

Comment: I'm afraid that as of now your only solution is using `grep`. The [issue #7730](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7730) is a related one.